# Remove respective image onclick of close button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a one list page with edit column. When he click on edit it will open one edit page with all data which have list of image in thumbnail format. 
Now I put close icon to all images.each image have its unique id.

1) When I click on close icon it will hide remove respective image.

2) onclick of submit I want available image ids.

**PHP Code:-**

```
 <div id="<?=$rw['id'];?>" style="height:68px; width:86px; margin-right:10px; float:left;">
            <img src="img/icons/close.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:top; height:18px; width:18px; z-index:9999;" >
                <div style="height:50px; width:70px; border:1px solid #999; float:left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;">
                <a class="group<?=$i;?>" href="<?=$img_gpath;?><?=$rw['upload_url'];?>" title="">
                <img src="<?=$img_gpath.$rw['upload_url'];?>" style="height:50px; width:70px; z-index:999;" id="<?=$i;?>">
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please if you have any solution then share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

add common class for div and dynamic id also
now you have only dynamic id;
if you use common class we can write jQuery like this 
 
**HTML**

```
<div id="<?=$rw['id'];?>" class="common">
  ----elements
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 jQuery('.common').on('click',function(){
     var element_id=jQuery(this).attr('id'));// u will get dynamic id of div; after that u can do anything by using this id  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

An example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL8Aw/1/) is created. Please check.

Please give a class of `remove-img` to the remove buttons.

```
<img class="remove-img" src="url" />
```

Then you need to remove the parent division on click of the remove image like:

```
$('.remove-img').click(function(e) {
    $( this ).parent().remove();
});
```