# Remove image on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/kL8Aw/1/)

I want to remove only image and not the whole div on clicking the cross button. I  took [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772778/remove-respective-image-onclick-of-close-button) from here.

```
    $('.remove-img').click(function(e) {
        $( this ).parent().remove();
    });
```

Comment: And what is your problem/question?

Comment: add a class to the img tag and just use following 
`$('.remove-img').click(function(e) {
    $( this ).parent().find('.imgToRemove').remove()
});` Sorry! I updated your fiddle by mistake. but you can check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kL8Aw/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse to `parent()` then `.find()` image excluding the current image. Then you can use `remove()`

*Use*

```
$('.remove-img').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find('img').not(this).remove();

    //If you want to remove all images
    //$(this).parent().find('img').remove();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/53fd4sce/)

Comment: @Amanjot, To exclude `$('.remove-img')` image from being removed

Answer (score 0):

You could select the parent first and then use find().

```
$('.remove-img').click(function(e) {
    $( this ).parent().find('img').remove();
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL8Aw/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use both `.parent()` and `.find()`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/kL8Aw/5/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
$('.remove-img').click(function(e) {
    $( this ).parent().find("img").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="" style="height:100px; width:200px; margin-right:10px; float:left;">
    <img class="remove-img" src="http://www.dlwp.com/Templates/DLWP/Images/popup-close-button.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:top; height:18px; width:18px; z-index:9999;" >
    <div style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid #999; float:left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;">
        <a class="" href="#" title="">
         <img src="http://www.mytriptokerala.com/images/Attractions/Backwaters-1858256226.jpg" style="height:100px; width:200px; z-index:999;" id="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="" style="height:100px; width:200px; margin-right:10px; float:left;">
    <img class="remove-img" src="http://www.dlwp.com/Templates/DLWP/Images/popup-close-button.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:top; height:18px; width:18px; z-index:9999;" >
    <div style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid #999; float:left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;">
        <a class="" href="#" title="">
         <img src="http://sympol.cusat.ac.in/img/photo_grid/grid-img-07.jpg" style="height:100px; width:200px; z-index:999;" id="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="" style="height:100px; width:200px; margin-right:10px; float:left;">
    <img class="remove-img" src="http://www.dlwp.com/Templates/DLWP/Images/popup-close-button.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:top; height:18px; width:18px; z-index:9999;" >
    <div style="height:100px; width:200px; border:1px solid #999; float:left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;">
        <a class="" href="#" title="">
         <img src="http://wikitravel.org/upload/shared//thumb/6/65/Kerala_Backwaters.jpg/350px-Kerala_Backwaters.jpg" style="height:100px; width:200px; z-index:999;" id="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the first option of the function

```
$('.remove-img').click(function(e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    $(target).find("img").remove();
});
```